# Binding checkbox with label dynamically

Tags: javascript, checkboxlist

I want to bind checkbox with its respective label dynamically using its id. 
Below, input boxes are being created dynamically. I want to bind those with their respective label using id, as given in the code.

```
        <span wicket:id="tagList" style="width: 30%;"> <input
                wicket:id="check" type="checkbox" id="check1" class="checker"
                style="float: left; margin-right: 15pt;"><em> <label
                    for="check1" wicket:id="tag" style="float: left;" />
            </em><br></br>
            </span>
```

How can I do it using javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by 'bind them'? What should happen?

Comment: If they are generated dynamically, why can't you at the same time generate proper `id` and `for` attributes? What specifically do you have before the JavaScript, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: By binding them I mean check box should be checked when I click its label. And as the page is pure HTML, the id needs to created by JS. I am searching for samples regarding the same. CAn anyone give me any idea how should I approach?

Answer (score 1):

I created simple JS for you, http://jsfiddle.net/7V8Gd/3/

Hopefully it is enough to get you started

```
<input onclick="onCheckbox(this, '1');" type="checkbox" id="check_1" class="checker">
<label id="label_1"></label>
<input onclick="onCheckbox(this, 2);" type="checkbox" id="check_2" class="checker">
<label id="label_2"></label>
<script>
    function onCheckbox(chkbox, cid){
        if (chkbox.checked) {
    document.getElementById("label_" + cid).innerHTML='yay';
            }            
            else{
    document.getElementById("label_" + cid).innerHTML='no yay';
            }            
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew...but I am not able to get how can I create id of an element. In my example, id of checkbox should be same as for of label element.

Comment: well, this should be done via programming language, php for example

Comment: Ok...my pages are pure html...so I cannot use any scripting language...only JS is option...

Comment: In this case manually hardcode all id's - onclick event `this, '1'` where `1` is the last number of the id, which is `id="label_1"`